# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')' when using cast or convert function

Tags: java, sql-server

Hi I am able to run the below query in SQL Server 2012 without any issues

```sql
select pid 
from mydb.dbo.analysis  
where subject_key = ? and cast(my_date as date) = cast(? as date)  
order by my_date desc
```

But when this is executed through Java code, I am seeing below exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Here is how my query is defined:

```
<entry key="scanid">
    <bean class="com.myorg.prod.model.Select">
        <property name="expression" value="pid" />
        <property name="from" value="mydb.dbo.analysis " />
        <property name="where" value="subject_key = ? and cast(my_date as date) = cast(? as date)  order by my_date desc " />
        <property name="params" value="subject_key,acq_date" />
    </bean>
</entry>
```

I see this problem when I am using `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions to convert and compare the dates.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Subject_key)) ---- just remove the parentheses

Comment: Same for `pid))`. --- You get an error saying `Incorrect syntax near ')'`, so you should look for where you have `)` characters. How can the two instances of `))` not be obvious to you when you look for `)` characters?

Comment: Hey.. sorry..that was a typo in my initial question. update it now

Comment: Is this also a typo? `value="subject_key)` looks like an extra `)`

Comment: oh yes.. corrected it. thank you!

Comment: I can only see `value="subject_key = ? and cast(my_date as date) = cast(? as date)  order by my_date desc " />` but not `value="subject_key)`, can anyone enlighten me on what I'm missing here?